# In Java: How to access static property of dynamically referenced class?

Tags: java, class, syntax, static, properties

In Java: How to access static property of dynamically referenced class?
I'm giving a short example:

```
AppleTree.areTheyAllGrown=true;
```

I simply want to dynamically reference the class of the static property 'areTheyAllGrown' This static property can be member of AppleTree or may be member of some other class, which of cource will also have the same named static property: 'areTheyAllGrown'.

As long as my application logic requires me to have many other tree types like CherryTree, ApricotTree and etc., it means that interface TreeBehaviour would not be sufficient solution, because by setting 'areTheyAllGrown' specifically of AppleTree, I want to mark let's say: only my AppleTree instances for that, not all Tree instances. See?

You would say: make an AppleTreeImpl interface and put the property in there... well.. that would force hell of an interfaces, to create only for one property...Impl Interface for all my different tree types? Isn't there a more short solution?

Ofcourse I see many other ways to implement the whole stuff, and to work around the need of dynamic referencing to a class, however, I am interested If I can do it particulary by this method. Also without excess use of interfaces or additional helper classes, nor public properties outside the Tree classes.

Comment: (If anybody suggest reflection, I shall be very cross.)

Comment: Well, reflection is the only way to do what he described. Doing something else is surely a better idea. I'd suggest a `Map<Class<? extends Tree>, Boolean>` (which in fact is a Set).

Comment: @Tom ha ha, very funny. What else would one suggest in such a scenario?

Comment: @maaartinus how is a map a set?

Comment: This is simply not what static fields are for.

Comment: @Sean: Asking if something is an element of a set is like mapping to boolean. Actually, a Map<?, Boolean> has 4 possibilities: true, false, null and absent, but let's ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, reflection is the only way to do what he described. Doing something else is surely a better idea. I'd suggest a Map, Boolean> (which in fact is a Set).

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest putting this outside the classes. In another class `GrowingRegistry`, where you can have a map - `Map<Class, Boolean>`. And so you can do:

```
GrowingRegistry.setAllGrown(AppleTree.class, true);
```

Even better, you can implement an interface `Tree` that defines `getTreeType()` for example, and have the map `Map<TreeType, Boolean>`, where `TreeType` is an enum. So:

```
GrowingRegistry.setAllGrown(TreeType.APPLE, true);
```

To extend further, you can have `GardenProperties` object which holds all properties for the "garden".

And as I mentioned garden - the whole problems comes from the fact that you want to track all instantiated objects. And it is you who instantiates them, isn't it? So you can put all instances in your collections. For example:

```
Garden garden = new Garden();
garden.add(new AppleTreeImpl());
garden.add(new CherryTreeImpl());
```

There you can store the instances in a `List` or `Map`, and also use the garden for holder of all properties.

Comment: Skapi Bozho, I did figure out myself several solutions alike. However I'm not happy with them. They are somehow not elegant. See? I may have many other properties like setAllGrown, not only this one alone. However there are also solutions for this. The answer of my question is now contained as a comment above: 'Well, reflection is the only way to do what he described.' by maartinus. Thank you for your answer too.

Comment: @PatlaDJ do I understand correctly that you want a set of properties per class (and not per-instance) in a hierarchy? Note that for OO-problems reflection should be considered as a last resort. I believe there is rarely a need for reflection when it comes to OO problems.

Comment: "do I understand correctly that you want a set of properties per class (and not per-instance) in a hierarchy?" --- this is exacly what I want. And I want them referenced from common external class also, not only by their instances. After I just learnt that the only way to dynamically reference static property of a class is thru java.lang.reflection, now I plan to implement this hierarchy by external registry class, as you proposed.

Comment: I dont want to track all instantiated objects. I just want to set group properties to them from time to time, but the group as I said, must be referenced dynamically, from an external class.I already did the implementation, and guess what I used exactly '...Properties' name addition for the properies container class :)

Comment: @PatlaDJ - by not wanting to track them yourself, you are perhaps making a design mistake. If in the future you need to have two gardens, the JVM won't be able to provide the distinction (two static groups? :) )

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object, you could just do what you were proposing on the object directly.

If you have a class you *could* use reflection:

```
try {
    treeClass.getField("areTheyAllGrown").set(treeClass, true);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
    // Do whatever you want with the error
    // e.g.: e.printStackTrace();
    // Or you could add a throws declaration
};
```